# laravel many to many fetching data

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to build a menu according to user roles using many to many relationship. laravel is my first php framework and i am facing this issue

```
Unhandled Exception

Message:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_role.created_at' in 'field list'

SQL: SELECT `roles`.*, `user_role`.`id` AS `pivot_id`, `user_role`.`created_at` AS `pivot_created_at`, `user_role`.`updated_at` AS `pivot_updated_at`, `user_role`.`user_id` AS `pivot_user_id`, `user_role`.`role_id` AS `pivot_role_id` FROM `roles` INNER JOIN `user_role` ON `roles`.`id` = `user_role`.`role_id` WHERE `user_role`.`user_id` = ?

Bindings: array (
  0 => 1,
)
```

**user migration:**

```
<?php
class Users {

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function($table){
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username', 128);
        $table->string('password', 128);
        $table->string('firstname', 128);
        $table->string('lastname', 128);
        $table->date('dob');
        $table->string('phone')->nullable();
        $table->text('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    DB::table('users')->insert(array(
        'username' => 'admin',
        'password' => Hash::make('admin'),
        'firstname' => 'asdf',
        'lastname' => 'zxcv',
        'dob' => '1990-02-23',
        'phone' => '935735367'
    ));

}

function down()
{
    Schema::drop('users');
}

}
```

**roles migration:**

```
<?php

class Role {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function($table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('lable', 60);
            $table->string('url', 128)->default("#");
            $table->integer('parent')->default("0");
            $table->integer('level')->default("0");
            $table->integer('sort')->default("0");
            $table->integer('published')->default("0");
        });

    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('roles');
    }

}
```

**role_user**

```
<?php

class Access {

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('role_user', function($table){
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        });


    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('role_user');
    }

}
```

**user model:**

```
<?php 
class User extends Basemodel{
    public static $table = 'users';
    public static $timestamps = true;
    public static $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|min:3|alpha',
        'password' => 'required|min:3|alpha'
    );

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->has_many_and_belongs_to('Role');
    }

    public static function menu(){
        $roles = User::find(1)->roles()->get();
        return $roles;
    }
}
```

**Role Model**

```
<?php 
class Role extends Eloquent{
    public static $table = 'roles';

}
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

class Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {
public $restful= true;

public function get_index()
{
    return View::make('home.index')
        ->with('title','App Index')
        ->with('menu',User::menu());
}
```

can someone guide me on what to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, at first glance, the timestamp columns are missing in the `user_role` table.
If you add the two columns; `created_at` and `updated_at` to the table and set them to `datetime` it should fix it up for you!

Also by the looks of things, your `roles` table doesn't have these timestamps described above either. You should either add these or set a `public static variable` in the `Role` model to state that they aren't there. You can do this by writing `public static $timestamps = false`

Comment: @PapaSmurf What if I don't want to / can't add those fields? Any way to deactivate the fetching of those fields? (Tried using `public static $hidden = array('created_at')` but it didn't work.

Comment: @AeroCross Yes you can! As I've explained above you can write `public static $timestamps = false;` at the beginning of the model. Hope that helps :)